# IntelliTrace events window in VS 2015 is.. where?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, intellitrace, debug-diagnostic-tool

OK, so I've just installed new shiny VS 2015 and started to regret about that.
There's a new feature called Diagnostic Tools where you can observe memory and CPU usage, also this window shows IntelliTrace events. While the feature is nice to troubleshoot specific memory- and CPU-performance related issues, I don't want to *always* spy on those metrics as I used to solve problems only when they appear. So I turned off Diagnostic Tools - and voila, I can't see IntelliTrace events anymore, because VS 2015 shows them in Diagnostic Tools window, which I disabled.

Is there anybody who knows how to get IntelliTrace window back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable CPU Usage and Memory Usage tools in Diagnostics Tools window by unchecking them in Select Tools drop-down menu (see [here](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/00/00/00/45/92/metablogapi/8666.2_SelectToolsDropdown_12933C3A.png)). After that Diagnostics Tools window will show only IntelliTrace data.